# Why are there only the Democratic party and the Republican party currently in the US?

Tags: united-states, history, political-system, republican-party, democratic-party

I was looking at [the history of the political parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_parties_in_the_United_States), and I found out that John Adams was a member of the Federalist party, while his son John Quincy Adams was a member of Thomas Jefferson's Democratic-Republican party and then switched to the National Republican party. Andrew Jackson was the first President of the Democratic party. William Henry Harrison, the first President to die in office, belonged to a party called the Whig party. The Whig party was later replaced by the Republican party. Abraham Lincoln was originally a member of the Republican party and then he switched to a temporary party called the National Union party. Andrew Johnson continued with the National Union party after Lincoln's assassination, and then switched to the Democratic party.

My question here is: What is the history behind this evolution?

Comment: An American history book will tell you about the evolution of the various American political party systems. [Wikipedia has a lot of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_parties_in_the_United_States). This question shows a lack of basic research.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an observation among political scientists called [Duverger's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duverger%27s_law). It is not a law in the sense of the laws of physics or the laws of a state, but it is a repeatedly observed pattern. Duverger found that in countries with a [first-past-the-post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting) electoral system, there tend to be only two significant parties. Periods with more than two parties are generally transition periods.

The Whigs disintegrated over the slavery issue, and according to Duverger it was natural for the non-Democrats to coalesce into a new party after a bunch of upheavals.

Comment: The laws of physics are literally based on repeated observations; what's the comparison here?

Comment: I think it should also be noted that in the presidential election the vote goes to congress if no  one passes the 50% mark and that has an impact on how many parties that US has.

Comment: @uberhaxed: Soft vs hard science. If you observe one violation of a purported "law" of physics, then it's not a law anymore. If you observe Ross Perot winning a bunch of votes in the 90's, (or Theodore Roosevelt coming in second on the Progressive ticket) it doesn't invalidate Duverger's law. Duverger's law is a tendency, not an absolute.

Comment: @kevin by this logic there are no laws of physics since all models fail in some scenarios. In fact, the mainstream theories are not even compatible with each other for the most part.

Comment: @uberhaxed: Yes, if you take everything 100% pedantically literally, you can argue that all science is "soft" to at least a little extent, but physics is much hard*er* than political science.

Comment: @uberhaxed: Our best current models of the world all have flaws, but that doesn't mean fully accurate laws of physics don't exist. It means we don't know what they are.

Comment: @Kevin all I was saying was that science uses exactly the same process as described so that's a weird (and inaccurate) thing to say.

Comment: @uberhaxed: I am not going to debate philosophy of science with you in the comments section of somebody else's answer on Politics.SE. Please ask a new question on Philosophy.SE if you wish to discuss this further.

Comment: @uberhaxed, in politics **perceptions** matter. Duverger's law is being called a "law." To someone who presumably wasn't aware of it, I added the qualifier that it is a social sciences pattern, not a legal instrument or hard science. If you are not going to accept talking about these laws, would you next go complaining that a Monarch Butterfly isn't really royalty?

Comment: @o.m. the comparison to the legal concept written in the answer made sense (we are on a political forum and people can make that mistake). I'm trying to get you to remove the inaccurate (and irrelevant since no one would make this mistake) comparison to the sciences. You literally stated in your answer that unlike the laws of physics, Duverger's law uses repeated observations for its basis. It just reads like a stealthy way to insert some science denying statements in an accepted answer. I can of course just edit it myself since the statement is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @uberhaxed, as I read it the other commenters argue 2 to 1 against your position. You are free to write your own answer and to see how many votes it gets.

Comment: @o.m. I agree with the rest of the content of the answer but added a suggestion on where it could be improved. That's the point of comments. This SE is not a democracy so arguing 2 to 1 should not matter.

Comment: The "post" in "first past the post" is a [finish post](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=finish+post&t=h_&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images), not a [fencepost](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fencepost&t=h_&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images).

Comment: Canada is "first past the post." Nationally, Canada has three main parties, the liberals, the conservatives, and the NDP. Plus a regional party that is based in the province of Quebec and regularly gets the bulk of seats in that province. This has basically been the situation for at least 50 years.  The rule seems to be short on explantory power.

Answer (score 1):

There are not only the reps and dems. There are other political parties.

Some other parties include the [libertarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_Party_(United_States)),
the [communists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Party_USA), the [green party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Party_(United_States)), and the [democratic socialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Socialists_of_America) to name just four. There are lots of other groups that are smaller and less well organized.

The reps and dems dominate because they run a system that deliberately produces this result. It is called ["the two party system."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-party_system#United_States) There are a large number of things that are done quite explicitly to make it easier for the two main parties. This includes things like additional hurdles to get on a ballot, difficulty qualifying for tax breaks, difficulty getting included in debates, etc.

Plus, the reps and dems have party machinery that has been built up over many decades. This includes such things as political relationships among the various levels of govt (city, state, fed), relationships with members of the media, large cash reserves, contacts for mundane things like advertising, printing services, venues for various gatherings from conventions to planning sessions, etc. etc.

So how does it work? The reps and dems have a system where they get their candidates on the ballot automatically, but the libertarians or communists have to get petitions with many names. The fees are paid by the party. The party has existing advertising channels, merch suppliers, TV station buddies, etc. The reps and dems hold their debates without third parties. The party handles the legal aspects, gives their candidate the various tax break documents, and funnels party funding to their campaign. While all of that *could* happen for third parties, it is constrained.

So a politician with, call them "novel" ideas,  finds it vastly easier to pick one of the two existing parties and work within that. So you get "wings" of the reps and dems. The social democratic wing of the dems or the libertarian wing of the reps. And this tends to syphon off people who would otherwise be in a third party. They can get party support from a large party, and get elected. Or they can struggle "in the wilderness" with a third party.

So to get a third party in requires something unusual, even extraordinary. For example, the republicans were a third party that formed over the issue of abolishing slavery.

Answer (score -2):

There are some good observations from history in the previous posts, but the contemporary answer is based on two simple words, money and power.  Since these two parties have been in power for a long time now, they have been able to manipulate the laws so that it is very difficult and expensive for another party to gain a foothold in the U.S. Some would say that this is the cause of the present state of polarization in the culture.  For example, to be a candidate for many offices requires the gathering of thousands of signatures to be allowed to have the name printed on a ballot.  For statewide races, those signatures may have to be collected throughout the state.  To establish a Political Party and get candidates on the ballot is much more complex, even on a small scale... but with enough money, and lawyers that understand the process, and...and... and...

Comment: Money does not explain how the evolution of the political parties.

Comment: While this answer could do more to detail how exactly "they have been able to manipulate the laws", one important observation might be that neither the GOP nor the Democratic party should have much interest in changing the status quo. May well be one of the underlying reasons of the law of Duverger that is briefly mentioned in the other answer. As such I find this answer useful.